# Python: Sort Pandas MultiIndex by max value of specified colum

Tags: python, sorting, pandas, multi-index

I'm trying to sort a Python Pandas `MultiIndex` by the maximum value of a specific column, in this case `INFORMATION_SURPLUS_PCT`.

How can I sort the levels whilst maintaining the grouping and order of rows?

I have tried: `df.sort(['INFORMATION_SURPLUS_PCT'], ascending=False)`, but this loses the grouping of the rows. Any help is much appreciated!

**Current MultiIndex input:**

```
              INFORMATION_SURPLUS_DIFF  INFORMATION_SURPLUS_PCT  
   SYMBOL                                                         
   AAL    0                   0.000000                 0.000000   
          1                  -0.008466                 1.000000   
          2                  -0.011333                 0.000000   
   ADI    0                   0.000000                 0.000000   
          1                  -0.010781                 2.000000   
          2                  -0.010414                 0.000000
```

**Desired output:**

```
              INFORMATION_SURPLUS_DIFF  INFORMATION_SURPLUS_PCT  
   SYMBOL
   ADI    0                   0.000000                 0.000000 
          1                  -0.010781                 2.000000 
          2                  -0.010414                 0.000000  
   AAL    0                   0.000000                 0.000000  
          1                  -0.008466                 1.000000 
          2                  -0.011333                 0.000000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by first level, find [`max`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.max.html), [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sort_values.html) and get `index`. Last you can [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) `DataFrame` by first level - `level=0`:

```
print df
          INFORMATION_SURPLUS_DIFF  INFORMATION_SURPLUS_PCT
SYMBOL                                                     
AAL    0                  0.000000                      0.0
       1                 -0.008466                      1.0
       2                 -0.011333                      0.0
ADI    0                  0.000000                      0.0
       1                 -0.010781                      2.0
       2                 -0.010414                      0.0

print df.groupby(level=0)['INFORMATION_SURPLUS_PCT'].max().sort_values(ascending=False)
SYMBOL
ADI    2.0
AAL    1.0
Name: INFORMATION_SURPLUS_PCT, dtype: float64

idx = df.groupby(level=0)['INFORMATION_SURPLUS_PCT'].max().sort_values(ascending=False).index
print idx
Index([u'ADI', u'AAL'], dtype='object', name=u'SYMBOL')

print df.reindex(index=idx, level=0)
          INFORMATION_SURPLUS_DIFF  INFORMATION_SURPLUS_PCT
SYMBOL                                                     
ADI    0                  0.000000                      0.0
       1                 -0.010781                      2.0
       2                 -0.010414                      0.0
AAL    0                  0.000000                      0.0
       1                 -0.008466                      1.0
       2                 -0.011333                      0.0
```